For real values of $r, x, a; \text{ and } r\gt 0,$ show $|x-a|\lt r \iff x\in(a-r, a+r).$
Have, $|x-a| =\sqrt{(x-a)^2}.$
Hence, $|x-a|\lt r \implies (x-a)\lt r \lt -(x-a)$ implies:
(i) $(x-a)\lt r \implies x \lt a+r,$ 
(ii) $r \lt -(x-a) \implies -r \gt (x-a)\implies r \lt (a-x) \implies x\lt (a-r)$
But, in (ii) should have got: $x \gt (a-r)$
Edit:
I know that if $x= 5, a =2, r=4,$ then $|x-a|<r\implies r\gt -(x-a),\text{ & } r\gt (x+a);$ i.e. it is not true that $(x-a)\lt r(=4) \lt -(x-a);$ but do not know how to express $|x-a|\lt r.$

$|x - a| < r \iff -r<x-a<r \iff a-r<x<a+r \iff x \in (a-r,a+r)$.

So, the condition $r\gt 0$ is a must; as then $|x-a|\lt r$ is not possible.

For the first implication, you can look into this

Exactly $r >0$ is needed here.
